# Wants to install Eclipse Kura but failed to set up internet network after removing dhpcd5 package

Tags: raspbian, networking, software-installation, ubuntu, static-ip

I am trying to install Eclipse Kura on my raspberry pi. From the Kura website, it is said that the package dhcpcd5 is not compatible with Kura. After removing the package, I tried to follow the instructions from the Github link provided for a number of times to set a static IP address. I was able to follow through the instruction but after reboot the raspberry pi, I am not able to connect via Debian networking.

I am currently working on a console for the raspberry pi. I hope to use my laptop which is running on ubuntu 18.04 as a source of the internet.

Please advise.

The following link is the website for the Kura installation. 
https://eclipse.github.io/kura/intro/raspberry-pi-quick-start.html

Comment: `dhcpcd` is the default Raspbian network manager. If you deleted it normal Raspbian network support won't work. It must be an unusual package if it won't work with any network manager. The link you followed contains a number of errors. It links to my tutorial which specifically recommends against Debian networking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure your network (wlan0) if you did remove dhcpcd,
takes those few steps :

1. edit the interfaces file

   sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces

   ```
   # /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)

   # The loopback interface
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback 

   # Wired or wireless interfaces
   iface eth0 inet manual 

   allow-hotplug wlan0
   iface wlan0 inet manual 
      wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
   ```
2. edit the /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf :

   ```
       ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev  update_config=1 country=US network={ ssid="your_ssid" psk="your_ultra_secure_password" }
   ```
3. make sure you are using ipv4 :

   ```
   sudo dhclient -4 -v wlan0
   ```

now even though your wifi icon might still be blank if you type in iwconfig you should see a running wireless iface.